# Receving answers from a custom layer with scapy using StreamSocket

Tags: python, scapy

I am new to scapy and I am trying to create a custom IPP(Internet Printing Protocol) packet using scapy

```py
from scapy.packet import Packet
from scapy.fields import LEShortField, ShortField, IntField, XByteField, StrField

class IPP(Packet):
    name = "IPP"

    fields_desc = [
        LEShortField("version", 1),
        ShortField("Op-Id", 11),
        IntField("request-id", 11),

        XByteField("start", 1),

        XByteField("char-code", 71),
        ShortField("len", 18),
        StrField("attr1", b'attributes-charset'),
        ShortField("len-1", 5),
        StrField("attr-value1", b'utf-8'),

        XByteField("lang-code", 72),
        ShortField("len-2", 27),
        StrField("attr2", b'attributes-natural-language'),
        ShortField("len-3", 5),
        StrField("attr-value2", b'en-us'),

        XByteField("uri-code", 69),
        ShortField("len-4", 11),
        StrField("attr3", b'printer-uri'),
        ShortField("len-5", 34),
        StrField("attr-value3", b'http://192.168.80.189:631/printer1'),

        XByteField("end", 3),
    ]

    def guess_payload_class(self, payload):
        return payload
```

I added the following code into Python3.7/dist-packages/scapy/layers/ipp.py

Hence IPP (Internet Printing Protocol) is implemented using HTTP, I have added HTTP layer before custom IPP Layer

To manage TCP 3-Way Handshake I used scapy StreamSocket

```py
from scapy.layers.http import HTTP, HTTPRequest
from scapy.layers.ipp import IPP
from scapy.all import StreamSocket
import socket

ipp_request = HTTP()/HTTPRequest(
    Method=b'POST',
    Path=b'/printer1',
    Connection=b'Keep-Alive',
    Content_Type=b'application/ipp',
    User_Agent=b'Internet Print Provider',
    Content_Length=b'125',
    Host=b'192.168.80.189:631'
)/IPP()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    my_soc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    my_soc.connect(("192.168.80.189", 631))

    my_stream = StreamSocket(my_soc)
    my_stream.basecls = IPP

    reply, ans = my_stream.sr(ipp_request)
```

I am able to send the IPP Packet successfully, But I am not able to receive answers
I am getting response like

```
Begin emission:
Finished sending 1 packets.
.......
Received 7 packets, got 0 answers, remaining 1 packets
```

seems to not be working, Any help is greatly appreciated.